# React Native Move a component to an absolute position

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I would like to move a component using an Animated function to an absolute position on the screen.

Basically it works like that :

```
 this.state.pan = new Animated.ValueXY({x: 50, y:50})  

 Animated.spring(
   this.state.pan, { toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 } }
 ).start();
```

I'm  wondering how I can move the component, for example, to the top left corner of the screen.  The toValue is relative to the last position of the object.

Is there a trick ?

Comment: transform translate